# Google Chrome & Firefox replacing the application url with the machine IP Address and localhost application can't be accessed

Tags: java, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

Google Chrome & Firefox replacing the application url with the machine IP Address and localhost application can't be accessed. The same application is running using the same url in IE.

The url is like : http://localhost:5001/ApplicationName/

Already tried :::

1. Cleared the browser cache and hard reload
2. Modified the hosts file to uncomment the "::1" part
3. Tried accessing the application using the 127.0.0.1

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: In chrome, open this URL: "chrome://net-internals/#hsts"  
Then in the bottom Query domain, try to query 'localhost'.
If a result comes, then remove that result.

Comment: Tried this but it returns "Not Found". :(

Comment: Can u run "nslookup localhost" in the terminal and check if localhost is assign to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: No. It's not assigned. I am accessing the internet via a proxy server. It returns that server name and address and said **"can't find localhost: Non-existent domain"**.

Comment: If you are using linux /ubuntu; Go to etc/hosts file and check if there is a line as "127.0.0.1   localhost". 
If you are using windows, it should be in system32/drivers/etc/hosts (Not sure the path).
Please check and let us know.